# Failed to add subscript to the subtitles of facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my code

```
ggplot(final_df, aes(Dr, mean, group = beta2, color = beta2))+
           geom_point(aes(group = pars))+
           geom_line()+
           scale_y_log10()+
           scale_x_log10()+
           geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se, color = beta2),width = 0.2) +
           labs(x = "Dispersal rate", y = target_terms2[i])+
           facet_wrap(~beta1, labeller = as_labeller(function(value) {
             **return(paste("\u03B21\u2081 = ", value))**
           })) +
           labs(color = expression(beta[2])) +
           theme_classic() + 
           theme(legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.2))
```

[image]

As is shown, after failing to use expression(beta[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnyRu.png)) to change the subtitles, I tried to use unicode to achieve it. However, the subscript parts were missed and replaced by a grid. I've tried so many ways to correct it but all failed, please help me to figure it.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Godfrey Luo! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (good start, great first question!) and sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly randomly). Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Thanks to your encouragement, I will pay more attention to what you've mentioned in future questions!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using `label_bquote` on `mtcars`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  facet_wrap(. ~ cyl, labeller = label_bquote(beta[2] * ' = ' * .(cyl))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

You can also use `label_parsed` on preformed strings for the same effect (and possibly more control, if needed).

```r
transform(mtcars, beta2 = paste("beta[2] * ' = ' *", cyl)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ beta2, labeller = label_parsed) + 
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be just as easy to use `label_parsed` here, adjusting `beta1` within the passed data frame to make it a label that can be parsed as an expression.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(within(final_df, beta1 <- paste('Beta[1] ==', beta1)),
       aes(Dr, mean, group = beta2, color = beta2)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = beta2)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(0.4, 0.8)) +
  scale_x_log10()+
  labs(x = "Dispersal rate", y = "Species diversity") +
  facet_wrap(~beta1, labeller = label_parsed) +
  labs(color = expression(beta[2])) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.title = element_text(hjust = 0.2))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

We don't have your data, but the following data set is a reasonable approximation:

```r
final_df <- data.frame(Dr = rep(10^-(7:2), 8*7),
                       mean = rnorm(8*7*6, 0.6, 0.03),
                       se = 0.005,
                       beta1 = rep(seq(0.25, 2, 0.25), each = 6 * 7),
                       beta2 = rep(seq(0.5, 2, 0.25), 6 * 8))
```

Comment: Nice sample data!